# Java interview puzzle related to set

Tags: java, collections, set

I faced below Interview question.

what is the output of the below code.

```
package com.demo;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Short> set=new HashSet<Short>();

        for (short i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            set.add(i);
            set.remove(i-1);
        }

        System.out.println(set.size());
    }
}
```

It is giving output :10

But i am confuse why its output 10.

Anyone can answer me please what happening here.

Thanks

SItansu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal value `1` is of type `int`. The value `i - 1` is thus of type `int` and not of type `short` as `i` is. You're thus adding boxed instances of `Short` to the set, but removing boxed instances of `Integer`. The `remove()` method thus doesn't remove anything, because a `Short` is not equal to an `Integer`.

Comment: Also worth noting that you don't get a warning or error for type mismatches as remove is defined to take an argument of type `Object` even for `Set<T>`.

Comment: The compiler is indeed happy. My IDE, however (IntelliJ) is smart enough to warn me about this probable bug.

Comment: Ah, I'm using eclipse at the moment, but it shows nothing for this. Sigh. (Probably has a setting for this somewhere though....)

Answer (score 5):

The expression i-1 has type int and is autoboxed to an Integer object, so the program is adding Short objects to the set and then tries to remove Integer objects. The set has no Integer objects, so nothing is ever removed.